# Check each param Symfony

Tags: symfony

I have a Route to create User, and I need some parameters to get this.

For example my controller is like this:

```
$dataJson = json_decode($request->getContent(),true);
$data = new \stdClass();
$data->email = $dataJson['email'];
$data->pwd = $dataJson['pwd'];
$data->role = $dataJson['role'];
```

I need of all of the (email, pwd, role) to create my User. 
Do I have to check each param to invalidate my request?

e.g.

```
$dataJson['email'] == null ? 'error' : $dataJson['email']
$dataJson['pwd'] == null ? 'error' : $dataJson['pwd']
$dataJson['role'] == null ? 'error' : $dataJson['role']
```

Of course this isn't the right way, but How can I sure that my request is valid?

Comment: I have seen an approach that used [the OptionsResolver component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/options_resolver.html) for a similar problem: http://symfony.com/blog/push-it-to-the-limits-symfony2-for-high-performance-needs#retrieving-requests-data-optionsresolver-component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach I would take would be to have a value object and define validation rules for it.

You can load the object manually, for example:

```
$data = new VO\UserChangeRequest($dataJson['email'], $dataJson['pwd'], $dataJson['role']);
```

I would then check whether the object is valid:

```
$violations = $this->get('validator')->validate($data);
$isValid = 0 === count($violations);
```

The validations rules would be obtained by the validator component from your bundle configuration.

Here's an article explaining validation in Symfony2:

- http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html

P.S For your specific case I would rather use [JMSSerializerBundle](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle). It integrates nicely and upon using param converter you will end up with the object automatically instantiated and hydrated for you. It may be a bit challenging to setup at first.

Comment: thanks, Where do you create `$data = new VO/UserChangeRequest($dataJson['email'], $dataJson['pwd'], $dataJson['role']);` ? What is `new VO/UserChangeRequest` ?

Comment: All the lines are to be set in the controller. `VO/UserChangeRequest` is a class you have to create. For example: http://pastebin.com/2qmpnFcg

Comment: nice, I have to create a class like a model and validate each fields. I haven't model now because I use MongoDb, but it isn't a problem.

But anytime I have to check all parameters I have to create Class and use validate?

Comment: Yes, that is the main idea. :)